# Putting two commands together in iMacros?

Tags: command, lines, imacros

i wanted to ask how can i paste two commands together in one line?

It should be like instead of this:

```
PROMPT "HELLO"
WAIT SECONDS=10
```

They should be considered as one:

```
PROMPT "HELLO" || WAIT SECONDS=10
```

It is to create multiple result line after an if statemenent in iMacros, but since the if statement is done in one line, i need to put several commands in one line...

The if statement has be done! I only need to know how to put these two commands into one line!

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking I would strongly recommend using the JavaScript Scripting Interface, but here suggest a certain workaround for two commands (or more if adjusted):

```
' set "P" or "W" here
SET C "P"
SET C EVAL("var c = '{{C}}'; switch (c) {case 'P': s = 'UFJPTVBUJTIwJTIySEVMTE8lMjI='; break; case 'W': s = 'V0FJVCUyMFNFQ09ORFMlM0QxMA=='; break;}")

URL GOTO=javascript:(function()<SP>{try{var<SP>e_m64<SP>=<SP>"{{C}}",<SP>n64<SP>=<SP>"bWFjcm8uaWlt";if(!/^(?:chrome|https?|file)/.test(location)){alert('iMacros:<SP>Open<SP>webpage<SP>to<SP>run<SP>a<SP>macro.');return;}var<SP>macro<SP>=<SP>{};macro.source<SP>=<SP>decodeURIComponent(atob(e_m64));macro.name<SP>=<SP>decodeURIComponent(atob(n64));var<SP>evt<SP>=<SP>document.createEvent("CustomEvent");evt.initCustomEvent("iMacrosRunMacro",<SP>true,<SP>true,<SP>macro);window.dispatchEvent(evt);}catch(e){alert('iMacros<SP>Bookmarklet<SP>error:<SP>'+e.toString());}})<SP>();
```

Comment: Ehm,... How would my code look like in combination with this?

Comment: The if statement has be done! I only need to know how to put these two commands into one line!